# VS 2019 Ctrl + , is not behaving as VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ide, regression, visual-studio-2019

I remember if I typed `Ctrl + ,` in VS 2017 I could navigate to almost everything that had the typed characters, But in VS 2019 it searches only files.
Here is what 2019 looks like

[image: Related Image]

But in 2017 it suggest the `UserController` file because it contains that method!

How can I have that feature back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/fixing-intellisense-and-go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-2019/) blog post:

> It turned out the issue was related to NuGet; what I needed to do was
>   delete the contents of the packages folder.  For completeness's sake,
>   here's the steps to do what I did.
>
> Close all instances of Visual Studio 2019. Delete the contents of the
>   packages folder at the root of your solution on your local machine.
>   Open Visual Studio 2019 again. This final solution worked for me.  I
>   am including the potential solutions in this post in the hopes that
>   one of them (actual or potential) works for you, dear reader.  Let me
>   know if you have any other solutions in the comments!

Deleting local nuget packages worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The new Visual Studio 2019 header search box, seen at the top of the screen, is designed to find anything in Visual Studio — including menu items, settings,tool windows and more. The tool uses fuzzy search that return the correct information even if you make a typo.

[image]